# Is it possible to view/modify a generic windows virtual print driver's code to redirect where a "printed" file is sent?

Tags: c, windows, printing, driver, wdk

I'm new to driver development, and basically I was wondering if I can take a virtual driver created by the windows print wizard, and view/modify the code somehow using VS2019 with the WDK integrated. I am trying to make a driver that redirects the file to be printed to a URI. If that's not possible, could someone point me to some samples that may help me out?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible if the driver allows access to it from any process.

in that case:

**first**, start by finding where the driver is:

you will find most of the drivers in windows under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` if you didn't find what you looking for there, use this command in an elevated cmd (admin) `driverquery.exe /v` it will list all the drivers and their location and some other information about them.

**second**, reverse the driver IOCTL so you can communicate with it,
you will need Windbg, and you have to do some kernel debugging to figure out  how the use mode communicate with the driver, just type
`!drvobj driver_name 7` then you will see some IRP_XXXXXXXX
you have to figure out which one is used to communicate with the driver, then start by reversing that function for that you can use Windbg, IDA PRO, Ghidra, or any good reversing tool to load the driver to and start seeing how should you construct your IOCTL  so that you can get an idea of how you can communicate with it.

after finishing that it is easy from here, you have to write the appropriate code in user mode to call the driver and then take the output and do what you like with it.